# Lodash uniqBy function not returning the unique data from an array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an array of object which looks like

```
const test = [{'activity': {'Name': 'Peter'}}, {'activity': {'Name': 'Peter'}},
{'activity': {'Name': 'John'}},{'activity': {'Name': 'Derek'}}]
```

Here I have used this function

```
const uniqBuyingSessions = _.uniqBy(
      buyingSessions, 'Name'
    )
```

It returns only the first object, in any case .

So, I was expecting the result to be

```
const test = [{'activity': {'Name': 'Peter'}},
{'activity': {'Name': 'John'}},{'activity': {'Name': 'Derek'}}]
```

So, Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `Name` property on your objects.

lodash traverses every object and try to read `Name`, which resolves to `undefined`. Since it will return undefined for every object, only the first one is returned (standard uniq behavior).

`Name` is actually a nested property (`activity.Name`).

I think this should work:

```
const uniqBuyingSessions = _.uniqBy(
  buyingSessions, 'activity.Name'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const test = [
{ 'activity': { 'Name': 'Peter' } },
{ 'activity': { 'Name': 'Peter' } },
{ 'activity': { 'Name': 'John' } },
{ 'activity': { 'Name': 'Derek' } }
];

const uniq = _.uniqBy(test, item => {
return item.activity.Name;
});
console.log(uniq);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```